# How to make logout without using sessionConcept in java

Tags: java

I am Developing an java web application.In that application I need to make logout without using session concept.If the user is idle for 2 mins I want to make him logout.

Is there any concept regarding above issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the problem with the session concept ?

Comment: There is a requirement that dont use session in the entire application.

Comment: who made that requirement and why ?